# pandas.read_table working in Jupyter notebook but would not work in vi editor

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, text-files, vi

I am trying to read txt file containing the table with `pandas.read_table` by executing the following code.

I added `import pandas as pd` and the problematic code is `pstttable=read_table("pstttable.txt")`.

Obviously, the location of the txt file is correct and the same code works when working with Jupyter notebook from Windows.

However, I want to compile the code with .py file edited by vi editor from Linux terminal and the following error will occur.

`File "Global_Repeater_Search.py", line 22
    pstttable=pd.read_table("/Users/sgtsnu02/2019-2020_Intern/EQcorrscan/pstttable.txt")
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

I have no idea why this kind of error occurs. Is this problem inherent to pandas when working in Linux terminal?

Comment: As a matter of fact, I did not attach the full code, because the majority of code is irrelevant to the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was really stupid question.
I forgot to close parentheses of the line before `pstttable=pd.read_table("/Users/sgtsnu02/2019-2020_Intern/EQcorrscan/pstttable.txt")`.

This caused `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`.

Nothing is wrong with **vi** nor `pandas.read_table`.